# std::cin.getline doesn't wait for Input

Tags: c++, console, std, cin, getline

Took the Example from [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/chat/chat_client.cpp).

Relevant Code:

```
    char line[chat_message::max_body_length + 1];

    while (std::cin.getline(line, chat_message::max_body_length + 1))
    {
        chat_message msg;
        msg.body_length(std::strlen(line));
        std::memcpy(msg.body(), line, msg.body_length());
        msg.encode_header();
        c.write(msg);
    }

    c.close();
    t.join();
```

The Application instantly exits without waiting me to put a chat message in. 
I made no modifications to the Code expect using a Windows instead of a Console Application (I'm still attaching a console with Alloc&AttachConsole)

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, your `std::cin` istream is invalid. `std::cin.getline` returns a reference to a `std::istream`, which represents `std::cin`. Walking back the inheritance hiearchy, `std::basic_ios`, which `std::cin` derives from, has an `operator bool` overload that will return false if either the `badbit` or `errorbit` on your stream has been set.

I'm betting your console, since not set up in a traditional manner, is not being properly attached to `std::cin`.